# Synonym request: font-lock and font-lock-mode

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

1. Tags [font-lock](/questions/tagged/font-lock) and [font-lock-mode](/questions/tagged/font-lock-mode) are, I think, Emacs-specific (and Elisp-specific) and can be merged. `font-lock-mode` should be made a synonym of `font-lock` (the master).
2. In addition, tag [syntax-highlighting](/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting) is more general (not Emacs-specific) and includes `font-lock`. I don't know how such subsetting is dealt with generally. Should an Emacs post about font-locking be tagged with both or just `font-lock`? If a post is tagged only with `font-lock` will someone not familiar with the name "font-lock" and looking for syntax highlighting Q&A for Emacs find the post?

Comment: A post about font locking in Emacs should be tagged both [tag:emacs] and [tag:font-lock]. I have no idea what you're saying about [tag:syntax-highlighting] here.

Comment: By "both" I meant the two tags I just mentioned: `syntax-highlighting` and `font-lock`. (There is no question about using tag `emacs` --- of course that should be used here.)  The question was about tagging with a parent category, `syntax-highlighting`, in addition to the child (subset) category, `font-lock`. Font-lock is syntax highlighting, but not vice versa. Someone looking for syntax highlighting in Emacs might not know the term `font-lock` and so might search for `syntax-highlighting` and miss a post that does not have that tag.